# Quantum Boolean SAT algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, satisfiability, quantum-computing, sat-solvers

Is there a quantum SAT algorithm, a quantum analogue of the DPLL or CDCL algorithms?

<sup>Note: I'm not looking for the quantum analogue of the Boolean satisfiability problem (though that would be interesting), but a quantum algorithm that solves Boolean SAT problems.</sup>

Comment: You can use Grover’s algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I figured something like that, but wouldn't the search space be too big?

Comment: Define "too big".  I suspect some requirements are missing from the question.  It is trivial to come up with an exponential-time algorithm.  What are your requirements on the running time of the algorithm?  Also, anything you can implement on a conventional computer, you can also implement on a quantum computer, so DPLL and CDCL can already be used on a quantum computer (they can be viewed as quantum algorithms).  Perhaps you want to know whether SAT can be solved more efficiently on a quantum computer than on a conventional computer?

Comment: Asked on [cstheory.se]: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36428/do-any-quantum-algorithms-improve-on-classical-sat

Comment: @D.W. "_Perhaps you want to know whether SAT can be solved more efficiently on a quantum computer than on a conventional computer?_" Yes.